# Why isn't tidycmprsk seeing the outcome that I want to plot?

Tags: r, survival

I have competing risks data with 4 potential outcomes.  I don't have any censored cases, so I've added a blank factor for the first level.

I'd like to plot the risk for outcome #2.  But when I run the code below, I get an error:

> Error in `ggcuminc()`: ! Argument `outcome` must be one or more of "3"

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

```
library(tibble)
library(dplyr)
library(tidycmprsk)
library(ggsurvfit)

mydata<-tibble::tribble(
  ~DAYSWAIT, ~WL_Outcome_factor,  ~devtype,
  8,                "3", "VV_ECMO",
  10,                "2", "VV_ECMO",
  37,                "2", "VA_ECMO",
  234,                "2", "VV_ECMO",
  5,                "2", "VV_ECMO",
  239,                "3", "VV_ECMO",
  15,                "2", "VV_ECMO",
  7,                "2", "VV_ECMO",
  34,                "4", "VV_ECMO",
  137,                "2", "VV_ECMO",
  55,                "2", "VV_ECMO",
  12,                "3", "VV_ECMO",
  38,                "4", "VV_ECMO",
  13,                "2", "VA_ECMO",
  22,                "2", "VV_ECMO",
  19,                "3", "VA_ECMO",
  16,                "2", "VV_ECMO",
  3,                "2", "VV_ECMO",
  3,                "3", "VV_ECMO",
  232,                "4", "VV_ECMO",
  2,                "2", "VV_ECMO",
  9,                "3", "VA_ECMO",
  60,                "3", "VV_ECMO",
  14,                "2", "VV_ECMO",
  15,                "3", "VV_ECMO",
  6,                "4", "VA_ECMO",
  11,                "3", "VV_ECMO",
  42,                "4", "VV_ECMO",
  2,                "4", "VV_ECMO",
  1,                "2", "VA_ECMO",
  25,                "3", "VA_ECMO",
  66,                "2", "VV_ECMO",
  10,                "2", "VV_ECMO",
  21,                "2", "VV_ECMO",
  16,                "2", "VV_ECMO",
  14,                "3", "VA_ECMO",
  3,                "4", "VV_ECMO",
  21,                "2", "VA_ECMO",
  7,                "2", "VV_ECMO",
  684,                "2", "VV_ECMO",
  10,                "2", "VV_ECMO",
  31,                "3", "VV_ECMO",
  25,                "3", "VA_ECMO",
  35,                "4", "VA_ECMO",
  43,                "3", "VV_ECMO",
  5,                "2", "VV_ECMO",
  6,                "3", "VA_ECMO",
  2,                "2", "VV_ECMO",
  9,                "4", "VV_ECMO",
  43,                "2", "VV_ECMO") %>%
  mutate(WL_Outcome_factor = WL_Outcome_factor %>%
           factor(levels=1:4))

cuminc(Surv(DAYSWAIT, WL_Outcome_factor) ~ devtype, mydata) %>%
  ggcuminc(outcome = "2") +
  add_confidence_interval() +
  add_risktable()
```

Comment: What is the meaning of the levels in `WL_Outcome_factor`? The data you've posted here has only `2` and `3`. Are these both events (i.e. competing risks)? Is anyone in the data censored?

Comment: Edited data to include 2,3,4.  The WL_Outcome_Factor are three different outcomes - died, transplanted, other.  Nobody is censored, but tidycmprisk requires the first level to be censored, so the factor is assigned levels 1:4.

Comment: I think this is a bug in `tidycmprsk`. If you create the model object, `cuminc_model <- cuminc(Surv(DAYSWAIT, WL_Outcome_factor) ~ devtype, mydata)`, the `ggcuminc()` function uses the table stored in `cuminc_model$tidy`. You'll see this drops the first level of the factor _which appears_ as censored, regardless of the factor levels. As a workaround you could add a new row with outcome `1` at time 0. This will work but it's a bit of a hack. Otherwise use a different package I think.